# Example of unbounded closed linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis

I am looking for one example for following case:

Linear operator $T:A\subseteq X\rightarrow Y$, such that $A$ is closed in $X$, $T$ is closed operator but not bounded. By closed operator I mean if there is sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ such that $x_n\rightarrow x$ in $X$ and $Tx_n\rightarrow y $ in $Y$, then we have $x\in A$ and $Tx=y$.

I thought about this. Is this fine ?

$T:(C^1 [0,1], \| \cdot \|_\infty) \rightarrow (C[0,1], \| \cdot \|_\infty)$ defined by $(Tf)(x)=f'(x)$. Here, I have taken $A=X=C^1[0,1]$. So only thing I needed to verify was if $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $C^1[0,1]$ such that $Tf_n\rightarrow g$ in $C[0,1]$, then $f'=g$, which is fine and this operator is also unbounded which can be shown using $f_n=x^n$. Is this Ok? I would also like to know one example where $A$ is proper closed subspace of $X$. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the first question, your example is ok. As to your second question, let $A$, $Y$ and $T$ be as in your example, and let $X = A \oplus <f>$, where $f \in C[0,1] \backslash C^1[0,1]$.

Comment: Your operator $T$ is bounded because $\|Tx\|_{Y}=\|Tx\|_{\infty}=\|x'\|_{\infty} \le \|x'\|_{\infty}+\|x\|_{\infty}=\|x\|_{X}$.

Comment: Isn't the counter example I gave right?  Means ${ x^n }$ is bounded set in domain but $nx^{n-1}$unbounded in codomain